# Select specific subsample per iteration (xgboost)

Tags: python, xgboost

Using xgboost it is possible to define the subsample ratio so that per iteration a certain percentage of the data is used. However, is is possible to specify the exact subset that should be used? The only way I can think of doing this using xgboost is to manage the iteration procedure myself as in https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/boost_from_prediction.py . And specify a different `dtrain` every iteration (`dtrain` would then contain a specific subsample everytime).

Is there a more elegant way to do this?